# Second user can't log in

Tags: login, gdm

This is 21.10 on top of a previous 21.04. When I try to log in with a second user (either an old existing one or a newly created one), the system freezes.

I log in as the primary user. Then, I try to switch users: I get to the login screen, type in the password, the screen goes black and then comes back to the login screen. I see the input field and the pointer, but the computer is frozen - I can't access a console.

If I reboot, I can log in to a different user, but if then I try to log in to the primary user, the same thing happens.

This only happens when switching between users. If I log out of the current user (end session) I can sign into the second account without any problem.

Comment: How are you creating new users?

Comment: GUI, adduser, useradd....